# Does the print construct behave differently when using parentheses?

Tags: php, boolean, operators, expression

I am not sure if parentheses make difference or I am doing something wrong!
Here is a situation I accidentally encountered..

```
 print (FALSE or TRUE);     //prints '1'
 print FALSE or TRUE;       //prints nothing
```

We know that `FALSE or TRUE` evaluates to `TRUE`, but surprisingly, printing `TRUE` is not affected by parentheses!

```
  print (TRUE);     //prints '1'
  print TRUE;       //prints '1'
```

The manual mentions clearly that using parentheses is not required! Here is a quote from the manual..

> print is not actually a real function (it is a language construct) so you are not required to use parentheses with its argument list.

**What I want to know ..**

- Is it a bug?
- If it is not a bug, how do parentheses affect the output?
- Which way gives expected output, using parentheses or omitting them?

*I am using PHP Version 5.4.7 on Windows 8.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (FALSE or TRUE);     //prints '1'
```

evaluates `FALSE or TRUE` (which gives TRUE), and then prints the result of that evaluation

```
print FALSE or TRUE;       //prints nothing
```

prints FALSE (which is displayed as an empty string); and if that fails (or) then does nothing with TRUE

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is operator precedence: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

it looks like `print` has the same operator precedence as assignment operators which have higher precedence than `or`.

If you try the same example but with `||` instead of `or`

```
print FALSE || TRUE; //1
```

the printed value will be 1 because `||` has higher precedence than assignment operators.

Hope that makes sense.